# How to safely prevent status callback function from being called in Wininet?

Tags: c++, wininet, winhttp

We are using WinInet inside a DLL to make asynchronous network calls.

When the application exits, we remove the registered callback functions for pending requests by using `InetSetStatusCallback(connect_handle, NULL);`. However, occasionally the callback function still gets called after the DLL has unloaded, leading to application crashes.

The symptoms are exactly similar to the last FAQ of this blog: [WinHTTP Questions: About Callbacks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wndp/2008/03/03/winhttp-questions-about-callbacks/#comment-11035)

I am trying to figure out a way to safely remove callback functions for all pending requests so that they are not called by WinInet after the DLL has unloaded.

Comment: Add a non-DLL dummy callback.

Comment: Any details on how setting a non-DLL dummy callback different from setting NULL callback ? Why is this expected to work ?

Comment: Create a function that does nothing in your code and set it as a callback. However this is only a temporary solution, you should check the code for race conditions.

Comment: Are you aborting the requests, and waiting for them to fully abort, before unloading the DLL?

Comment: @remy We are calling `InternetCloseHandle` on root internet handle returned from `InternetOpen` but not on the `InternetConnect` handles derived from root handle. Will closing all open `InternetConnect` handles before closing root handle solve this ?

Comment: @ShashankGupta of course you must close all handles that you open. The documentation even says so : "*After the calling application has finished using the HINTERNET handle returned by InternetConnect, **it must be closed using the InternetCloseHandle function**.*"

Answer (score 0):

after we pass pointer to callback function - module which containing this callback function of course must not be unloaded, until callback may be called. this is of course not problem if callback function was in *EXE* module, which never will be unloaded. but in case *DLL* we need add reference to *DLL* before set callback, for prevent *DLL* unload. this is easy can be done via [`GetModuleHandleExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandleexw) function

```
HMODULE hmod;
GetModuleHandleExW(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, (PCWSTR)&__ImageBase, &hmod);
```

ok, but how not let *DLL* be unloaded ? we need dereference it (call [`FreeLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibrary)) when our callback will be no more called. when this will be ?

the [`InternetSetStatusCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetsetstatuscallback) sets up a callback function for some handle. this handle of course should ever be closed via [`InternetCloseHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetclosehandle) and:

> It is safe to call **InternetCloseHandle** in a callback for the handle
>   being closed. If there is a status callback registered for the handle
>   being closed, and the handle was created with a non-NULL context
>   value, an **INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING** callback will be made. This
>   indication will be the **last callback** made from a handle and indicates
>   that the handle is being destroyed.
>
> If asynchronous requests are pending for the handle or any of its
>   child handles, the handle cannot be closed immediately, but it will be
>   invalidated. Any new requests attempted using the handle will return
>   with an **ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE** notification. The asynchronous requests
>   will complete with **INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE**. Applications must
>   be prepared to receive any **INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE**
>   indications on the handle before the **final**
>   **INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING** indication is made, which indicates
>   that the handle is completely closed.

so [`INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nc-wininet-internet_status_callback) - will be the **last** callback made from a handle. **finall** call. exactly at this time we need defereference *DLL* module - callback will be no more called. not need reference more.

ok. when is clear. but how ? we can not direct call `FreeLibrary` from this point, because if *DLL* live on this last reference - it will be unloaded inside `FreeLibrary` call and when we return - we return to the emply space and crash.

we can not call [`FreeLibraryAndExitThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibraryandexitthread) too - because we on arbitrary thread. however exist **not correct** but worked on practic solution:

```
ULONG WINAPI SafeUnload(void*)
{
    //Sleep(*);
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread((HMODULE)&__ImageBase, 0);
}

if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, SafeUnload, 0, 0, 0))
{
    CloseHandle(hThread);
}
```

we can create new thread yourself, and from this thread call `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` (here this call is correct). but how i say - this is theoretically **not correct** solution. here exist **race** - the `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` call can execute and unload *DLL* **before** we return from `CreateThread` call. as result we crash just after `CreateThread` (we try execute already unloaded code). of course this is unlikely, but..

we can insert `Sleep` (some delay) before call `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` but anyway - can be race theoretically for any delay. again what concrete value for delay select ?! and *DLL* will be delayed unload for this time. not correct and not nice. despite this is relative simply "solution" i be not use it.

correct solution will be - call (more exactly **jump**) to `FreeLibrary` without return to place, from where this jump will be. but hust return to place, from where callback was called. this is impossible in *c/c++* but possible in *asm* code. of course this require separate *asm* file for every platform target (*x86, x64* how minimum)

so correct and elegant solution is next: the [`INTERNET_STATUS_CALLBACK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nc-wininet-internet_status_callback) callback function anyway must be associated with some class, where we hold handle context. this must be static function in class and *DWORD_PTR dwContext - application-defined context value associated with hInternet* must point to the instance of class (by fact *this* pointer). usually this is done in next way:

```
class REQUEST_CONTEXT 
{
  // ...
    static void WINAPI _StatusCallback(
        __in  HINTERNET hRequest,
        __in  DWORD_PTR dwContext,
        __in  DWORD dwInternetStatus,
        __in  LPVOID lpvStatusInformation,
        __in  DWORD dwStatusInformationLength
        )
    {
        reinterpret_cast<REQUEST_CONTEXT*>(dwContext)->StatusCallback(
            hRequest, 
            dwInternetStatus, 
            lpvStatusInformation, 
            dwStatusInformationLength
            );
    }

    void StatusCallback(
        __in  HINTERNET hRequest,
        __in  DWORD dwInternetStatus,
        __in  LPVOID lpvStatusInformation,
        __in  DWORD dwStatusInformationLength
        );
};
```

be here we need implement `_StatusCallback` in *asm* code for call `FreeLibrary` here. and chage return value of `StatusCallback` from *void* to *BOOL* - *TRUE* we return if this is final call (`dwInternetStatus == INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING`) and *FALSE* otherwise.

so begin solution

```
// helper for get complex c++ names for use in asm code
#if 0
#define ASM_FUNCTION {__pragma(message(__FUNCDNAME__" proc\r\n" __FUNCDNAME__ " endp"))}
#define CPP_FUNCTION __pragma(message("extern " __FUNCDNAME__ " : PROC ; "  __FUNCSIG__))
#else
#define ASM_FUNCTION
#define CPP_FUNCTION
#endif
```

base class skeleton:

```
class REQUEST_CONTEXT 
{
    // ...
    static void WINAPI _StatusCallback(
        __in  HINTERNET hRequest,
        __in  DWORD_PTR dwContext,
        __in  DWORD dwInternetStatus,
        __in  LPVOID lpvStatusInformation,
        __in  DWORD dwStatusInformationLength
        ) ASM_FUNCTION;

    BOOL StatusCallback(
        __in  HINTERNET hRequest,
        __in  DWORD dwInternetStatus,
        __in  LPVOID lpvStatusInformation,
        __in  DWORD dwStatusInformationLength
        );

    ULONG SendRequest(PCWSTR pwszObjectName);

    void OnRequestComplete(HINTERNET hRequest, INTERNET_ASYNC_RESULT* pres);
};
```

`StatusCallback` implementation:

```
BOOL REQUEST_CONTEXT::StatusCallback(
                    __in  HINTERNET hRequest,
                    __in  DWORD dwInternetStatus,
                    __in  LPVOID lpvStatusInformation,
                    __in  DWORD dwStatusInformationLength
                    )
{
    CPP_FUNCTION;

    switch (dwInternetStatus)
    {
    case INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CLOSING:
        Release();
        return TRUE;
    case INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE:
        OnRequestComplete(hRequest, (INTERNET_ASYNC_RESULT*)lpvStatusInformation);
        break;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

how we register callback (in my code inside `SendRequest` for handle returned from [`HttpOpenRequestW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-httpopenrequestw) )

```
ULONG SendRequest(PCWSTR pwszObjectName)
{
    // ... some code ...
    AddRef();

    HMODULE hmod;
    if (GetModuleHandleExW(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, (PCWSTR)&__ImageBase, &hmod))
    {
        if (HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequestW(..., (DWORD_PTR)this))
        {
            set_handle(hRequest);

            if (INTERNET_INVALID_STATUS_CALLBACK != InternetSetStatusCallback(hRequest, _StatusCallback))
            {
                INTERNET_ASYNC_RESULT ar;
                ar.dwResult = HttpSendRequestW(hRequest, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                ar.dwError = ar.dwResult ? NOERROR : GetLastError();

                if (ar.dwError != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
                {
                    OnRequestComplete(hRequest, &ar);
                }

                return NOERROR;
            }
        }

        FreeLibrary(hmod);
    }

    Release();

    return GetLastError();
}
```

so here we call `GetModuleHandleExW` for add reference to *DLL* before set callback. if set callback fail - we call `FreeLibrary` for deference *DLL*. note that here call `FreeLibrary` safe and correct, because the one who called `SendRequest` must have reference for *DLL* - *DLL* of course must not be unloaded during this call. so when we call `FreeLibrary` from this function - we **guaranteed** to release not the last reference to *DLL* (we free reference from `GetModuleHandleExW` call, but exist additional reference on *DLL* during this function executing. the caller (direct or indirect) of this function care about this). in place *dwContext* we pass *this* pointer.

so now final part - `_StatusCallback` implementation.

for *x64* (*ml64 /c /Cp $(InputFileName) -> $(InputName).obj* )

```
extern __imp_FreeLibrary:QWORD
extern __ImageBase:BYTE

; void REQUEST_CONTEXT::StatusCallback(void *,unsigned long,void *,unsigned long)
extern ?StatusCallback@REQUEST_CONTEXT@@QEAAHPEAXK0K@Z : PROC 

.CODE 

?_StatusCallback@REQUEST_CONTEXT@@SAXPEAX_KK0K@Z proc
    xchg rcx,rdx
    mov rax,[rsp + 28h]
    sub rsp,38h
    mov [rsp + 20h],rax
    call ?StatusCallback@REQUEST_CONTEXT@@QEAAHPEAXK0K@Z
    add rsp,38h
    test eax,eax
    jnz @@1
    ret
@@1:
    lea rcx, __ImageBase
    jmp __imp_FreeLibrary
?_StatusCallback@REQUEST_CONTEXT@@SAXPEAX_KK0K@Z endp

end
```

for *x86* (*ml /c /Cp $(InputFileName) -> $(InputName).obj* )

```
.MODEL FLAT

extern __imp__FreeLibrary@4:DWORD
extern ___ImageBase:BYTE

; int __thiscall REQUEST_CONTEXT::StatusCallback(void *,unsigned long,void *,unsigned long)
extern ?StatusCallback@REQUEST_CONTEXT@@QAEHPAXK0K@Z : PROC 

.CODE

?_StatusCallback@REQUEST_CONTEXT@@SGXPAXKK0K@Z proc
    mov ecx,[esp + 8]
    push [esp + 20]
    push [esp + 20]
    push [esp + 20]
    push [esp + 16]
    call ?StatusCallback@REQUEST_CONTEXT@@QAEHPAXK0K@Z
    test eax,eax
    jnz @@1
    ret 4*5
@@1:
    mov eax,[esp]
    lea edx, ___ImageBase
    add esp,4*4
    mov [esp],eax
    mov [esp + 4],edx
    jmp __imp__FreeLibrary@4
?_StatusCallback@REQUEST_CONTEXT@@SGXPAXKK0K@Z endp

end
```

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you should wait/cancel all pending async calls.
Leaving them alive and unloading the code is not nice (correct) at all.